# How can I used Rails "gt" or "lt" with where statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following relationship in my model.

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :visitor
end
```

```
class Visitor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visits
end
```

And I'm trying to do
`visitors.where(visits.count.gt(value.to_i))`

which throws

`NoMethodError (undefined method visits for <Visitor::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007ff2f0c77578>):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query wise what you want is:

```
SELECT "visitors".* FROM "visitors" 
INNER JOIN "visits" ON "visits"."visitor_id" = "visitors"."id" 
GROUP BY visitors.id 
HAVING (count(visits.id) > ?) 
LIMIT $1
```

The reason you want `HAVING (count(visits.id) > ?)` and not `WHERE (count(visits.id) > ?)` is that you are setting conditions on an aggregate.

You can create this query either with SQL strings:

```
Visitor.joins(:visits)
       .group('visitors.id') # you can just use :id on PG - other drivers are not as smart
       .having('count(visits.id) > ?', 5)
```

Or with Arel:

```
Visitor.joins(:visits)
       .group(Visitor.arel_table[:id])
       .having(Visit.arel_table[:id].count.gt(5))
```

Using Arel is theoretically more portable as the table names are not hard-coded.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are to get visitors who has more than certain amount of visits. Then you can try the below way -

```
Visitor.joins(:visits).group('visitors.id').having('count(visitor_id) > ?', value.to_i)
```